# Search a word using regular expression

Tags: javascript, mysql, regex, search

How to search a word in exact match, for example how to search word '`leak`', but search results should not include words like '`leaked`' or '`leaks`' etc.

Help in both **Javascript** and **MySQL** would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need to look for word boundaries. So don't think of looking for the word `leak`, but looking for the word `$leak#`, where `$` is an imaginary character that is at the beginning of every word and `#` is an imaginary character at the end of every word (Not a standard convention, just assume it for this example). The words are delimited, by, lets say whitespaces for now. So, `leaked` and `leaks` is `$leaked#` and `$leaks#`. As such, the only part that matches is `$leak` and not `$leak#`.

To do that in **MySQL**, the condition would be:

```
REGEXP '[[:<:]]leak[[:>:]]';
```

Here, `[[:<:]]` is the *begin-word word-boundary* and `[[:>:]]` is the *end-word word-boundary*.

For **JavaScript**, the query would be:

```
/\bleak\b/
```

Here, the sequence `\b` represents a *word-boundary* (in javascript, there is no distinction between begin-word and end-word boundaries). It won't only work for whitespaces, but even punctuation characters, for example:

```
.leak
,leak
;leak
```

will match `/\bleak\b/`, but `aleak` will not. (I am unsure about MySQL though)

Comment: *$* the beginning of a word? AFAIK *$* is for end of string. *\b* is for word boundaries.

Comment: I was giving it as an illustration, completely language-agnostic, but yeah, I see how that could cause a confusion :)

Comment: Wrote a disclaimer on m0skit0s suggestion. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: The MySQL documentation says *[[:<:]]* is word boundary, so I would take it as *\b* equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The regex would be

```
/\bleak\b/
```

Usage in JavaScript

```
var patt1=/\bleak\b/i;
patt1.test(your_string); // Returns true/false
```

For MySQL ([I didn't know it had support for regexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), thanks Rohan Prabhu):

```
expr REGEXP [[:<:]]leak[[:>:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match words that don't start with leak*

```
(?!leak\w*)\b\w+\b
```

Matches in bold:

- **notleaked** leaks leak leaked

Answer (score 0):

```
\bleak\b
```

I've tested it on the following inputs:

1. leaked or leak. 'leaks' etc.
2. leak, hello
3. find:leak-hello
4. hello world!leak